# Finding `uniq` values in array with their indexes

Tags: ruby

Let say I have an array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
```

I wonder how I can get the hash `{ 1 => 0, 4 => 3 }` (`value => index`). I need the index of the earlier occurrence.

Comment: What do you mean "I need index of earlier occurence"? if you need only UNIQUE elements, they they only occur once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could also try this

```
unique = array.select { |a| array.count(a) === 1 }
indexes = unique.map { |u| array.index(u) }
Hash[unique.zip(indexes)]
```

My algorithm is to first generate a new array of the single elements. I do that by filtering the array for the one's where the count is equal to 1. We can use the `array#count` method.

I then create a second array, where I map the values of the first array, to their indexes in the original array.

I then combine the values using the `array#zip` function and convert to a hash with `Hash`.

**Output**

```
{ 1 => 0, 4 => 3 }
```

Comment: This is very expensive, complexity of O(n^2)

Comment: Understood, that's why I edited the post. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: As a note you could cut this down one line by using `Hash[unique.map{ |u| [u,array.index(u)]}]` rather than `map` and then `zip` just zip them in the mapping. OR even a 1 liner would be `Hash[array.select{|a| array.count(a) == 1 }.map{ |u| [u,array.index(u)]}]`

Answer (score 2):

```
a.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(e, i), h| h.key?(e) ? h[e] = nil : h[e] = i }
 .reject! { |k, v| v.nil? }
```

Comment: For readability, perhaps you should use some other value (like `nil`) instead of `-1`.

Comment: You can also use `.each_with_index.with_object({}){|(e, i), h|` to make it look better.

Comment: rather than overwriting duplicate values then rejecting them why not avoid inserting them at all e.g. `a.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(e, i), h| h[e] = i if a.count(e) == 1 }`

Comment: you can put the assign first, i.e. `h[e] = h.has_key?(e) ? nil : i` and instead of rejecting `nil` values, you could select non-`nil` values using `select { |k, v| v }`

Comment: note that `reject!` returns `nil` if nothing was rejected, you have to use the non-bang methods (either `reject` or `select`)